# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I trying deploy my App In Heroku, and this error appears:

```
 2018-05-03T14:35:40.682441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver`
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960741+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960765+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960858+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960872+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960873+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960875+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960876+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960879+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-05-03T14:35:41.960895+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
2018-05-03T14:35:41.961003+00:00 app[web.1]:     ) from exc
2018-05-03T14:35:41.961016+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
2018-05-03T14:35:42.013265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-03T14:35:42.008966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

My requirements.txt:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.8.1
numpy==1.14.2
psycopg2==2.7.4
python-decouple==3.1
pytz==2018.4
scipy==1.0.1
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

My runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.5
```

My Procfile (in 'myapphere' is my app name)

```
web: gunicorn myapphere.wsgi
web: python manage.py runserver
```

The problem is I make "git push heroku master' and the error appears, I don't know that happens...

Deploy Log:

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.11 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile…
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 53.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v21
remote:        https://sbceval.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/sbceval.git
   df538a8..a82ea89  master -> master
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not need to list django in your requirementes file?

Comment: But, is in requirements :

django-heroku==0.3.1

Comment: I have checked my projects that were deployed to heroku - their `Procfile` file contains the `gunicorn` line only, without `python manage.py runserver`. Not sure if this is the problem, though. And I also did not use `django-heroku`, that is why I asked about requirements

Comment: I remove command "python manage.py runserver", but the errors appears: 

bash: gunicorn: command not found

Comment: And in requirements there is "gunicorn==19.8.1". I thinking that heroku not found my requirements.txt.

Comment: My requirements is in root from project with this content:


dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.4
gunicorn==19.8.1
numpy==1.14.2
psycopg2==2.7.4
python-decouple==3.1
pytz==2018.4
scipy==1.0.1
whitenoise==3.3.1

Comment: Afaik heroku shows complete installation log while you are pushing, could you please post the log here? And you can also open bash into your heroku container and check that all requirements were installed

Comment: Add deploy log.

Comment: You said you have requirements.txt, but heroky says about Pipfile

Comment: It is! I have both files, I remove Pipfile and it's done! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

According to your log, you have both `Pipfile` and `requirements.txt`. Remove one of them and you should be fine

Comment: Yup. Removed pipfile and pipfile.lock and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the "pipenv lock" command and then delete the pipenv file before Heroku would accept it. They are so finicky and so unhelpful when these sorts of things happen!!!

Comment: It does answer the question, I had to run the "pipenv lock" command. I also deleted the heroku database with "heroku pg:reset" if that adds more information