# Application error - When I uploading my Django app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Uploading my Django app on Heroku

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail

heroku logs:

```
$ heroku logs -n 150
(node:19036) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: C:\Users\Meteor\AppData\Local\heroku\version: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
module: @oclif/config@1.13.2
task: runHook init
plugin: heroku
root: C:\Program Files\heroku\client
See more details with DEBUG=*
(node:19036) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: C:\Users\Meteor\AppData\Local\heroku\config.json: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
module: @oclif/config@1.13.2
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: C:\Program Files\heroku\client
See more details with DEBUG=*
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984311+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984311+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984312+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984312+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984312+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984313+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984313+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984314+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/newspaper_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984315+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984315+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-11-05T15:09:42.984555+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:42 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-11-05T15:09:42.992599+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:42 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-05T15:09:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001925+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:42 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001929+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001929+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001930+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001931+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001931+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001932+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001932+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001933+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001933+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001934+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001934+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001935+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001935+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001936+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/newspaper_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001937+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-11-05T15:09:43.001937+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-11-05T15:09:43.002169+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:43 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-05T15:09:43.149710+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:43 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-05T15:09:43.149823+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:43 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-05T15:09:43.250459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-05T15:09:43.303365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-05T15:09:43.306915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-05T15:09:49.074113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi`
2020-11-05T15:09:51.509525+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2020-11-05T15:09:51.510059+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:24987 (4)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.510167+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-11-05T15:09:51.511620+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
2020-11-05T15:09:51.511621+00:00 app[web.1]: return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.515120+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524599+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524600+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524601+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524601+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524602+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524602+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524603+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524603+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524604+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524605+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524606+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524607+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524607+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/newspaper_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524608+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524608+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-11-05T15:09:51.524784+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.530248+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536468+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536470+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536471+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536471+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536472+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536473+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536474+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536474+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536475+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536475+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536476+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536476+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536476+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/newspaper_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536477+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536477+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-11-05T15:09:51.536590+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-05T15:09:51.660520+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-05T15:09:51.660654+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:09:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-05T15:09:51.756274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-05T15:09:51.807711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-05T15:10:24.269598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=newspaper-2020.herokuapp.com request_id=a22f6b28-a334-420a-ade1-6f8e75560879 fwd="37.200.249.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-05T15:10:25.689071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newspaper-2020.herokuapp.com request_id=bf4c18e7-5264-4f33-ae49-5357c96309ce fwd="37.200.249.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-05T15:34:51.096827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=newspaper-2020.herokuapp.com request_id=e9eb3726-4dab-4a49-ae2b-20efa66ae8c6 fwd="37.200.249.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-05T15:34:52.078404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newspaper-2020.herokuapp.com request_id=148807ce-b410-4528-b799-86f3aa265fb0 fwd="37.200.249.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-05T15:39:03.883280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-05T15:39:09.428963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi`
2020-11-05T15:39:11.237450+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2020-11-05T15:39:11.238023+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:20576 (4)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.238148+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-11-05T15:39:11.239551+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
2020-11-05T15:39:11.239552+00:00 app[web.1]: return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.242528+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249559+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249561+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249561+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249561+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249562+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249562+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249563+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249564+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249564+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249565+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/newspaper_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249565+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249565+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-11-05T15:39:11.249689+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.268247+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275520+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275522+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275522+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275522+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275523+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275523+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275523+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275523+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275524+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275524+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275524+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275525+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275525+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275530+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275530+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/newspaper_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275531+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275531+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-11-05T15:39:11.275653+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-05T15:39:11.379193+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-05T15:39:11.379278+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-05 15:39:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-05T15:39:11.435045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-05T15:39:11.484782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-05T16:38:31.058784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=newspaper-2020.herokuapp.com request_id=a1ab1357-b3d9-4f51-81b8-4bbacd42eebd fwd="37.200.249.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-05T16:38:32.907711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newspaper-2020.herokuapp.com request_id=3bda3bf8-d10f-496a-a228-a35286e148e0 fwd="37.200.249.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Please, add more logs. So we can see the actual exception being raised.

Comment: Added more logs, Please check them

Comment: The error you get is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'". Did you install `django` package?

Comment: How are you getting Heroku to install your dependencies? Please include the file structure of your project, specifically the presence and contents of a `Pipfile` or `requirements.txt`. Have you searched for this problem before posting it here? Here's another similar question that was asked and answered some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50157862/9374673

Comment: Django needs to be added inside your requirements.txt - otherwise Heroku will not install it once you deployed your app there. That explains the ModuleNotFoundError: It 's not available at Heroku.